# Gradle plugin classpath in composite build

Tags: java, gradle

I have two projects - first is simple hello world and second is custom gradle plugin. This plugin has additional classes in dir `${pluginRoot}/some-classes`. I added them to dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile(files("some-classes"))
}
```

Inside task `work` I use those additional classes like this:

```
Class<?> aClass = SimpleTask.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("io.github.hejcz.A");
Object o = aClass.newInstance();
Object count = aClass.getDeclaredMethod("count").invoke(o);
System.out.println(count);
```

For testing I created main method invoking this behavior and it prints expected value.

Then I made composite build and added this plugin to hello world project, applying the plugin. Task `work` appeared in hello world project. On execution I get error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.hejcz.A
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at io.github.hejcz.SimpleTask.soutClassOnCP(SimpleTask.java:21)
   at io.github.hejcz.SimpleTask.hello(SimpleTask.java:14)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:692)
```

It seems the plugin does not see those additional classes any longer. How can I fix this?

**Update**

After some investigation I realised hello world project uses jar file generated from included project. There were no those additional classes in this jar. Adding following code to plugin's `build.gradle` solves the problem but is it the best way to achieve what I want?

```
task copyAdditionalClasses(type: Copy) {
    from "some-classes"
    into "build/classes/main"
}

jar.dependsOn copyAdditionalClasses
```

**Update**

After lance-java suggested to not copy classes I found another way to do what I want:

```
sourceSets.main.output.dir(file("some-classes"))
```

It makes `Jar` task to copy this dir during packaging.

Comment: Don't put extra classes in `build/classes/main` as it will ruin the up-to-date checking for the `compileJava` task

Comment: What's the alternative?

Comment: Wait, how can it break `compileJava`. It is needed in runtime so adding `copyAdditionalClasses.mustRunAfter compileJava` should solve this rpoblem.

Comment: Use a separate folder and add that folder to `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` instead. compileJava uses the classes directory for up to date checks, don't pollute that directory with files from another task

Comment: Its plugin so after packaging those classes wont be available

Comment: They will if you also  add them in the `jar` task. Eg `jar { from 'xxx' }`